# SIGABRT on NSDictionary objectAtIndex: unrecognized selector

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsarray, catiledlayer

I'm having a weird error here.
I have an array named __ImageData:

```
static NSArray *__ImageData = nil;
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ImageData" ofType:@"plist"];
NSData *plistData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSString *error; NSPropertyListFormat format;
_ImageData = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistData
                                              mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable
                                                        format:&format
                                              errorDescription:&error];
```

When I NSLog out the content of the array, I get this output:

```
2012-08-23 16:36:35.573 CAT[28814:c07] {
    "Item 0" =     {
        height = 7121;
        name = Map1;
        width = 8556;
    };
    "Item 1" =     {
        height = 7121;
        name = Map2;
        width = 8556;
    };
    "Item 2" =     {
        height = 7121;
        name = Map3;
        width = 8556;
    };
}
```

But when I NSLog out `NSLog(@"%@", [__ImageData objectAtIndex:0]);`, I get this exception:

```
2012-08-23 16:36:35.573 CAT[28814:c07] -[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: 
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x719d0f0
2012-08-23 16:36:35.574 CAT[28814:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: 
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x719d0f0'
*** First throw call stack:
```

etc..

I have no idea how to reach an object in this array.. It seemes like the objectAtIndex cant find any indexes, not even index:0, even though there is data inside.. Anyone know how to get it? 
I am using the PhotoScroller-template from Apple, using the `CATiledLayer`. I think the whole thing is kinda funky, but everybody says we should use this for large images. Anyone have an explanation or a better idea than CATiledLayer for huge images? (8556*7121px).

And why do I get Dictionary-error from the NSArray?
When doing `NSDictionary *dict = [__ImageData objectAtIndex:0]`, I also get the same exception.

Stian.

Comment: Beware, `+[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:mutabilityOption:format:errorDescription:]` is deprecated.  Also, double-check your variable capitalization?

Comment: @Hyperbole Ah, okay. I just kind of reverse engineered the Photoscroller-code from apple, and got few warnings. I now have no warnings, and no deprecated-lines over the code, so I assumed it was all good. I noticed the capitalization, this is not in the code, this is my bad in putting the code here.

Comment: @Hyperbole Hm, how do you know it is deprecated? I don't get any clues about NSPropertyListSerialization is deprecated anywhere..

Comment: `NSPropertyListSerialization` is not deprecated, it is the method `propertyListFromData:mutabilityOption:format:errorDescription` that is deprecated.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I switched to propertyListWithData instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_ImageData` is not an array, it is a dictionary.  To display the first element of the dictionary you could do something like:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [_ImageData objectForKey:@"Item 0"]);
```

Comment: Thank you! You are right.. But where does it convert to NSDictionary? The source code from Apple used the code I provided.. In their version it turned out as an Array.. Can I typecast to fix, or should I convert everything to fit with NSDictionary?

Comment: `_ImageData` is an `NSDictionary` because the data in the Plist has been stored as a dictionary not an array. Plists can store both arrays and dictionaries at their top level.  You can't typecast an `NSDictionary` into an `NSArray`, they are completely different data structures.  If you expect the data returned to be an array you need to look at the Plist file or the code that is creating the Plist file. Either fix the Plist file to be an array or convert your code to deal with `NSDictionary`.

Comment: I've had a look at the `Photoscroller` source code from Apple and the `ImageData.plist` file in their example has an array of dictionaries.  Your `ImageData.plist` file appears to be a dictionary of dictionaries.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this same issue using an JSON Array. My fix was to convert it to an NSDictionary like so:

```
[(NSDictionary *)json objectForKey:@"detail"];
```

Or you could do it like this:

```
NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary *)array;
```

Comment: This doesn't convert anything. json will be whatever it is, dictionary, number, whatever. _The compiler_ will think that it is a dictionary, and therefore will allow you to use NSDictionary methods, which will crash if it is not an NSDictionary*.